# Add default google maps tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tooltip

Is it possible to add default Google Maps tooltip, like this:

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/5502/tooltipr.jpg

to map on my own page?

I don't want (and don't need) to make custom tooltip.

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API 3.

Comment: [google it](https://www.google.hr/search?q=google+maps+tooltip+how+to&aq=f&oq=google+maps+tooltip+how+to) ?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

Google Maps has InfoWindow feature which allows to display tool tips like that on your map.

See more here [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows)

Comment: I know that i can make InfoWindow, but can i leave default `contentString` with chosen place description, photo and standard links below (like Direction, Search nearby, etc) ?

Comment: Its HTML. You can put whatever you want.